# Download file from protected website programmatically with Save As popup

Tags: c#, download, webforms, webbrowser-control

I use WebBrower of microsoft to log into a website. I have no problem with logging in.  I don't have the downloadable file url because the file is generated automatically.
How should I download file with out Save As popup to show ?

Answer (score 0):

Work with the DOM (document object model) of the website find your download link via traversing the DOM exposed by the browser control via it's property

```
Document
```

it is a tree of elements that your after-login page consists of. There should be some element that you should invoke click on it and then handle OnNavigating (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.onnavigating(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the control to get the generated download URL.